# How to create a list without indentation?

Tags: java, itext, itextpdf

Is it possible to create numbered list without indent ? Somethig like that :

1 A

1-1 A_A

2 B

2-1 B_B

2-1-1 B_B_B

Comment: Can you provide some pseudo code? Right now, it's not clear if you are talking about a nested list or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at the [ListNumbers](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/objects/ListNumbers) examples.

When we create an ordered list like this:

```
List list1 = new List(List.ORDERED);
list1.setFirst(8);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    list1.add("item");
}
document.add(list1);
```

We get a result like this:

[image]

Where necessary, extra space is added between the label and the content of a list item.

Your question is: how can we remove this indentation. That's a matter of adding a single line to your code:

```
List list2 = new List(List.ORDERED);
list2.setFirst(8);
list2.setAlignindent(false);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    list2.add("item");
}
document.add(list2);
```

Now the result looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, no extra space was added after items 8 and 9.

This answer is so simple that I can't believe that this was actually the whole question (if it was, that would mean that you didn't do any effort whatsoever yourself). Looking at the desired result, I assume that there is more at play then what you mention in the subject of your post.

I see:

- Custom numbering: no `.` after the number.
- A nested structure: 2, followed by 2_1, and so on.

Changing the list symbol in case of ordered lists can be done using the `setPreSymbol()` and `setPostSymbol()` methods.

Take a look at this snippet:

```
List list3 = new List(List.ORDERED);
list3.setFirst(8);
list3.setAlignindent(false);
list3.setPostSymbol(" ");
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    list3.add("item");
    List list = new List(List.ORDERED);
    list.setPreSymbol(String.valueOf(8 + i) + "_");
    list.setPostSymbol(" ");
    list.add("item 1");
    list.add("item 2");
    list3.add(list);
}
document.add(list3);
```

First we remove the dot that is added after each number automatically, we use the `getPostSymbol()` method for this:

```
list3.setPostSymbol(" ");
```

Then we nest `list` inside `list3`. As we want to get a result that looks like `8_1`, `8_2`, `9_1`, etc., we use the `setPreSymbol()` method like this:

```
list.setPreSymbol(String.valueOf(8 + i) + "_");
```

Now the result looks like this:

[image]

Obviously, one could argue: why do you want to use a `List` for this kind of result? Why not just a series of `Paragraph` objects. However: if you're creating Tagged PDF, it's better to use `List` because iText will then automatically tag that content as a list (e.g. in the context of accessibility).

Comment: @Valeriane Feel free to accept the answer if it solved your problem. (That way other people can see that the question was answered with the blink of an eye.)